# Is it possible to access a numpy array with strings?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a table like this:

[image: Matrix]

And I would like to access it like this in python

```
table["Water"]["Rice"] = 3
```

Is this possible with numpy.ndarray ?

Comment: What do you mean by `table`?  There isn't such an object class in Python (or `numpy`).

Comment: That's basically a dictionary. Arrays have indices, dictionaries have keys. Indices can only be integers, keys can be any type. They're two different data structures. Short answer is no.

Comment: You might want to try pandas... anyways this isn’t a clear question, try to add input in more specific way...

Answer (score 7):

Assume that you created the source *Numpy* array as:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 3, 1],
                [2, 5, 3],
                [5, 6, 7]])
```

But "ordinary" *Numpy* arrays have no "symbolic" indices (names).
They have **only** integer indices, starting in each dimension from *0*.

You can define in *Numpy* so called **structured arrays**, but they
allow for symbolic names only within a row.
Such an array is composed of rows (indexed by an integer index) and
each row is a collection of named fields.
But you want symbolic names for **both** rows and columns, so *Numpy*
structured arrays are not an option for you.

In my opinion, the only reasonable choice is to use *pandasonic*
DataFrames, where you can have symbolic names for both columns and rows.

In *Pandas*:

- *index* is a collection of "names" for each row,
- *columns* is actually also an *index*, but it holds
  names of columns.

To create a DataFrame from the above *Numpy* array, you can run e.g.:

```
# Names of columns and rows (the same)
names = ['Water', 'Rice', 'Sauce']
# Actual creation of a DataFrame
table = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=names, columns=names)
```

Its content is:

```
       Water  Rice  Sauce
Water      1     3      1
Rice       2     5      3
Sauce      5     6      7
```

To read an element from this DataFrame, you can use your code, i.e.:

```
table['Water']['Rice']
```

In the above code:

- *Water* (the first index) is a column name,
- *Rice* (the second index) is a row index (name),

so the value read is *2*.

But a more *pandasonic* way to access elements of a DataFrame is:

```
table.loc['Water', 'Rice']
```

This time however:

- *Water* (the first index) is a row index,
- *Rice* (the second index) is a column name,

so the value read is *3*.

You can also save a new value in an indicated cell, e.g.:

```
table.loc['Water', 'Rice'] = 12
```

Now, when you `print(table)`, the result is:

```
       Water  Rice  Sauce
Water      1    12      1
Rice       2     5      3
Sauce      5     6      7
```

If you perform some operations on this DataFrame (*table*), but you want then
to integrate it with other code, expecting to work with a *Numpy* array
(not a DataFrame), you can pass it as:

```
table.values
```

i.e. you pass the underlying *Numpy* array.

But then you can refer to elements of this array again only using
integer indices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I came across Numpy's structured arrays. But did not quite understand it. So thank you for explaining it.Panda looks interesting. I solved it now in another way. I created my own Class "my_array" which basically is a numpy.ndarray. I overwrote the "__getitem__" and "__setitem__" to look up the given string in a dictionary (string -> int) and use this int to get/save the value in the ndarray and return it. I can use this Class just as i wanted. But i'm not sure if it is a good Solution performance wise. What do you think?

Comment: *Numpy* is known to operate faster that *Pandas* and it is important especially for big arrays. You can compare execution times of both versions, e.g. using *%timeit*. Maybe your solution will be faster? Try it.

Comment: Does this work for higher-dimensional arrays? E.g. a 3D array.

Comment: Unfortunately, *Pandas* supports only 1D and 2D arrays. And my solution "diverged" from the original concept to use *Numpy*. So based on *Pandas*, in my opinion, it is not possible.